# Filtered Drop Down list items and search in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, filtering

I have a drop down list and when user types something in the same, the drop down list must show the filtered options to be selected. I have done the code behind but filtering is pending.

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="AppraisersDpd" runat="server" Width="134px" 
         CssClass="dropdownpersonal textfont" 
         onselectedindexchanged="AppraisersDpd_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The code behind is also there which is running:

```
     AppraisersDpd.DataSource = apprblobj.FillAppraisers();  //fills Appraisers drop down
        AppraisersDpd.DataTextField = "AppraiserName";
        AppraisersDpd.DataValueField = "AppraiserId";
        AppraisersDpd.DataBind();
```

can any one suggests me some clue? Should I use Combo box or I am going right?

Comment: _"I have a drop down list and when user types something in the same"_ An ASP.NET `DropDownList` is not editable, so what control are you using?

Comment: What is the difference between combo box and dropdown list?

Comment: Easy way around is to for Ajax Autocomplete or Jquery Autocomplete controls

Comment: You might want to try Telerik RadComboBox

Comment: @ Tim Schmelter: I got the point, it means I must use combo box instead of drop down.

Comment: You can use the [Ajax Control Toolkit Combobox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx) or the [jQuery UI counterpart](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

Comment: @codingbiz: A [`ComboBox`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx) is editable wheras a `DropDownList` is not ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require some Javascript to be implemented; as none of the ComboBox server-side events fire when you type something in a combo.  I suggest you use a 3rd party ComboBox control that supports the "auto-complete" feature.  The [Ajax Toolkit ComboBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx) control may work out for you.

Comment: Okay, I have used Telerik combo box and I think I must better use Combo box instead of dropdown.

Comment: I use Telerik ASP.NET controls and they are very good.  I wanted to suggest something free though.

Comment: If I use a Combo box then also I would like to know the clue to do the same, search results on Google are also showing auto complete feature which I don't require.